# Is there a way to forcibly center the whole page or remove margin-right?

Tags: css, reactjs

Thanks for opening this post in advance.

Here is the reproduction.
https://frolicking-meerkat-06f939.netlify.app/

**Goal:**
My goal is to center this div.home-text (blue area) and remove margin-right; so it prevents visitor scrolling to the right empty space unintendedly.

**Problem:**
This works perfectly on desktop viewpoint, larger screen.
But I cannot catch any idea that why I cannot centre the page area plus, margin-right with no value. (Please view the below image)

[image]

This symptom persists only on specific page, Home.
I doubt this might be due to 'react-pdf' hook I used...still, adjusting margin-left did not solve the issue nor removing the margin-right with no value but space.

Did I setup a wrong media query...? What should I do?

```
// Home.js

import React from "react";
import "./Home.css";

// pdf
import { Document, Page } from "react-pdf/dist/esm/entry.webpack5";

import HomePDF from "../../pdf/resume.pdf";

function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="home-wrapper">
        {/* layer very back */}
        <div className="home-content">
          <div className="home-text">
            {/* profile picture, box */}
            <img
              className="profile"
              src={require("../../images/me-photo.jpg")}
            />
            <hr />
            {/* pdf */}
            <div className="pdf">
              <Document file={HomePDF}>
                <Page scale={1.5} pageNumber={1} />
                {/* <Page size="A4" style={styles.page} /> */}
              </Document>
            </div>
            <hr />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

```
// Home.css
.home-wrapper {
    /* width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    text-align: center; */

    /* width: 100%;
    height: calc(100vh - 100px);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center; */

    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
}

.home-content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

.profile {
    border-radius: 20%;
    height: auto;
    width: 280px;
    /* insurance */
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 1rem; 
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.home-text {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
}



.react-pdf__Page__canvas {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 1rem;

}

.react-pdf__Page__canvas {
    width: 600px;
    height: 800px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .home-wrapper {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .home-text {
        max-width: 400px;

    }

    .pdf {
        max-width: 300px;
    }

    .react-pdf__Page__canvas {
        max-width: 390px;
        max-height: 550px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm hard to tell with just that. Would you have a minimum reproduction available?

Comment: Here is the reproduction link. https://frolicking-meerkat-06f939.netlify.app/

Comment: I think you should add margin auto in your media queries as well. Please try it.

Answer (score 0):

From what I could see, the problem is that you are maxing the width of containers while you only should be maxing the size of the pdf...

Replacing

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .home-wrapper {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .home-text {
        max-width: 400px;

    }

    .pdf {
        max-width: 300px;
    }

    .react-pdf__Page__canvas {
        max-width: 390px;
        max-height: 550px;
    }
}
```

By

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .react-pdf__Page__canvas {
        max-width: 390px;
        max-height: 550px;
    }
}
```

Seemed to give good results.

Be aware also that if you'd like to always have a margin no matter the screen width, you could use a percent of the viewport instead of fixed pixels with a media query, something like `max-width:90vw` will make the pdf always take 90% of the screen's width.